# Having issue in testing with spring cloud stream with kafka binding

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

**I have following Binding**

```
public interface KafkaBinding {
    String DATA_OUT = "dataout";

    @Output(DATA_OUT)
    MessageChannel dataOut();
}
```

**Here is kafka utility**

```
     @EnableBinding(KafkaBinding.class)
        public class KafkaStreamUtil {



 private final MessageChannel out;

        public KafkaStreamUtil(KafkaBinding binding) {
            this.out = binding .dataOut();
        }
        public void SendToKafkaTopic(List<data> dataList){


   dataList
            .stream()
            .forEach(this::sendMessgae);
}

private void sendMessgae(Data data) {
    Message<Data> message = MessageBuilder
            .withPayload(data)
            .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, data.getRequestId().getBytes())
            .build();
    try {
        this.out.send(message);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(),e);
    }

}
```

**My test class**

```
            @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
            @ActiveProfiles("test")
            @SpringBootTest(classes = {KafkaStreamUtil.class,KafkaBinding.class})
            @DirtiesContext(classMode= DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
            public class KafkaStreamUtilTest {



                private static final String TEST_TOPIC1 = "data";
    private static final String GROUP_NAME = "embeddedKafkaApplication";

    @ClassRule
    public static EmbeddedKafkaRule kafkaRule =
            new EmbeddedKafkaRule(1, true, TEST_TOPIC1);

    public static EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafka = kafkaRule.getEmbeddedKafka();


    @Autowired
    private KafkaStreamUtil kUtil;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaBinding binding;


    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupProperties() {
        System.setProperty("spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers", embeddedKafka.getBrokersAsString());

        System.setProperty("spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
        System.setProperty("spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.key.serde", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde");
        System.setProperty("spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.value.serde", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde");

        System.setProperty("spring.cloud.stream.bindings.dataout.destination", "data");
        System.setProperty("spring.cloud.stream.bindings.dataout.producer.header-mode", "raw");

        System.setProperty("spring.autoconfigure.exclude","org.springframework.cloud.stream.test.binder.TestSupportBinderAutoConfiguration");
        System.setProperty("spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

        System.setProperty("spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.headerMode","raw");
        System.setProperty("spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group","embeddedKafkaApplication");
        System.setProperty("spring.kafka.consumer.group-id","EmbeddedKafkaIntTest");



    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        kUtil = new KafkaStreamUtil(binding);
    }


    @Test
    public void sendToKafkaTopic() {


        kUtil.SendToKafkaTopic(dataList);


        Map<String, Object> consumerProps = KafkaTestUtils.consumerProps(GROUP_NAME, "false", embeddedKafka);
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        consumerProps.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        consumerProps.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, String> cf = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerProps);

        Consumer<String, String> consumer = cf.createConsumer();
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton(TEST_TOPIC1));
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(10_000);


        consumer.commitSync();
        consumer.close();
        Assert.assertNotNull(records);



    }


}
```

**I am unable to get binding with Kafka util in test the binding is always null. Please let know what I am missing. I am able to test with springboottest but it is loading all beans I just want to load necessary componens required for this test.**

Comment: The binding comes as null maybe a red herring. This is proxied by an internal framework bean. If you call `binding.dataOut()`, I think it will work. If you can share a full sample, we can take a look further. When you use embedded kafka, you also need to pass its host/port as the broker address to the binder.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I have updated the question with detail code. Please take a look and let me know

Comment: if I execute this test with following then it works
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class KafkaStreamUtilTest {

But I do not want to load the all dependancies

Comment: Looks like some auto-configuration still has to be added into your sliced test configuration. Would be great to see some simple project to play with. At least that way we will know what versions you use.